# Salesforce Trigger Infinite Loop

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, infinite-loop

To start, we have a product that syncs data to and from salesforce via the api. When a record is updating in our platform, the data is pushed to salesforce, when the data is updated in salesforce, it is pushed to our product. The problem we're running into is an infinite loop that is being rather troublesome. Is there a way in SalesForce to determine who is executing a trigger so that when data is updated in our product and pushed to salesforce, the trigger will not fire? I haven't seen an execution information about this before so I'm really not sure on it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything beyond Trigger.isExecuting, which simply tells you whether you are already in a trigger context or if you're coming from Visualforce, the API, or execute anonymous.

One possible solution is to create a custom field that retains the origin of the most recent update. This can then be used to properly route logic within your triggers and avoid calling out when the last update is from your external system. Additionally you can loop through all fields in your Trigger.old and trigger.new to see which fields changed. This way you can avoid further unnecessary syncs to your external system when nothing interesting actually changed on your record (SystemTimeStamp, LastModifiedDate, etc.) Here's a sample of how to do this:

```
trigger ContactDescribeExample on Contact (before update) 
{
      // Get describe fields to evaluate old and new triggers with
      Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fldObjMap = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap();
      List<Schema.SObjectField> fldObjMapValues = fldObjMap.values();

      // Flag to determine if field(s) other than FirstName caused this change (FirstName is just an example)
      Boolean hasOtherChange = false;

      // Loop through trigger batch
      for(Contact c : Trigger.new)
      {
            for(Schema.SObjectField s : fldObjMapValues)
            {
                  String fldName = s.getDescribe().getName();

                  // Filter out fields we're not interested in
                  if(fldName != 'FirstName' && fldName != 'LastModifiedDate' && fldName != 'LastModifiedById' && fldName != 'SystemModstamp')
                  {
                        // Check to see if old and new are different
                        if(c.get(fldName) != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).get(fldName))
                              hasOtherChange = true;
                  }
            }
      }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this certainly helped and I think will definitely go into solving this issue. I appreciate the swift reply!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this on Google I worked around a very similar issue by adding a class that sets a public static variable that the triggers then check for. It's false by default, and if it's set to true the triggers don't run. Example below:

```
public class Recursive {
  // Static variables to avoid recursion on trigger operation

  private static boolean working = false;

  public static boolean isWorking() {
      return working;
  }

  // Set variable to true to mark record as working

  public static void setWorking() {
      working = true;
  }

  public static void setClosed() {
      working = false;
  }

}
```

Then the triggers are wrapped in the following:

```
if (!Recursive.isWorking()) {
  // trigger code here
}
```

Being a static variable, it stays set throughout the code execution, so the first thing my apex sets is `Recursive.setWorking();` to prevent triggers from firing throughout the rest of the methods.

Comment: 2 questions. 1 - Where/when do you reset the flag? 2 - What if someone else is updating the data from the SF UI?

Comment: I don't manually reset the flag anywhere, as it only persists within the bounds of the class/trigger that calls it. If someone else is updating the same data, their instance of the trigger will have its own instance of Recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Adam on how to better identify when to perform a synchronization. You might also consider looking at the user that is currently updating the record using the UserInfo.getUserId() method and then looking up the user.

I imagine that in order for your integration to work you had to assign a user to the external product. Hopefully, that is an account unique to them which would be the best practice. If so then you can just look at who the current user is and if it is that external product you can ignore attempting to send another update back out.

Answer (score 0):

For each "exempt source" for which you want to have logic filtered out, you create a field on the target object of type Number(18,0). I usually call this field something like "Last Updated by [Job]". The field should not be on any user-facing page layouts.

Then, whenever your exempt source performs an update, you set that field to System.currentTimeMillis(). Your triggers check if that field has changed, and if it has, you exempt the logic that you wish to omit for that source.

The solution Adam mentioned - to retain the source of the most recent update - would also work but I find it can be error-prone if you are not always properly updating it or checking if it has changed. That's why I prefer a field that changes when you want a logic exemption, and you only have to update it for those exempt sources of change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a dedicated user for the API calls coming in from your product then you could disable the [Send Outbound Messages](https://cs4.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_userperms.htm#SendOutboundMessages) User Permission for them. This won't stop some of the trigger code from running, but it will prevent any update cycle every developing.